# Jupyter-Flex on Databricks

Tags: jupyter, databricks

I am using python Jupyter-Flex to replicate a R flexdashboard. I am able to create a html dashboard in my local in jupyterlab. Can I create the same in Databricks. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have done this before in the databricks you can use ipywidgets==7.6.5 in the databricks library section. I was running the 6.4 Spark version in the databricks so I specify version number you can go without the version number.

Comment: I am trying to build a dashboard/static html where I need to show plots for around 20 different regions. Now as there are no Dropdown option for static html I tried to create tabs, but that is kind of going out of bounds is there a way to create a dropdown menu or increase the layout automatically to increased number of tabs? Is this idea feasible or am I missing something?